# JMeter isn't posting an xml with the parameter dataxml correctly

Tags: java, jmeter

I am testing a spring mvc controller's action which takes a xml file and processes it.

In jmeter I created a request sampler, set it to HTTP POST at localhost:8080/api/xml/new

I then added the xml file, and set the parameter name to 'dataxml'.

In my controller I have:

```
String dataxml = request.getParameter("dataxml");
```

In debug mode I trace the call that jmeter makes and it is null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're uploading an XML file, that's different than retrieving a simple non-multipart form parameter. You need to provide more details regarding both the controller and its expectations, and the specific jmeter config.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the MIME type to `text/xml` help?

Comment: no that didn't help either, it is still null.  it works if I change it to a get request and add a param in the 'send params with request' section, but I want to POST the xml file, but it is ignoring the file I am sending it seems?  to I check the multi part checkbox?